# Fadein div for a specific time, then fadeoff

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create something like **notification messages** as a test.

So as example I have 5 divs and this is what should happen:

1. pick a random div
2. fade in
3. show/stop for 5 seconds
4. fade out

Additionally there are a few important things:

- It is allowed that 2 or 3 divs were displayed at the same time, depending on the random time pick
- The last faded in div should be on first position every time
- All divs should be displayed in maximum 5 Minutes

I could fake it with a simple css animation or a jquery fadein/stop/fadeout, but this is not my aspiration. I am trying different things for days now, but I do not get the solution - so I am asking you guys for help.

At the moment I have a random div picker. But I don't know, how to combine with fadein/fadeout and so on.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a9vjk968/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="first" class="notification">first</div>
<div id="second" class="notification">second</div>
<div id="third" class="notification">third</div>
<div id="fouth" class="notification">fourth</div>
<div id="fifth" class="notification">fifth</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.notification {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**JS**

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
$('.notification').hide().eq(random).show();
```

Thanks upfront guys!

Comment: *"I could [use] jquery fadein/stop/fadeout but [don't want to]"* If you don't want to use fadein/fadeout, what solution are you expecting?   Have you tried `delay()` rather than `stop` ?

Comment: Hide your div so fadeIn and fadeOut will execute. 
See.
https://jsfiddle.net/ud1os2w5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do? Since it is a notification tab, I created a dummy button that will trigger it. You should tweak it a little and generate each notification dynamically (PHP function, AJAX call etc.).

In a real web application approach. It would be nice if you will give your notification a parent div that will float somewhere (lower right/left or the screen).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#trigger').click(function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.notification').length);
    $('.notification').eq(random).fadeIn(5000).show().fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
.notification {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

#trigger {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="trigger">CLICK HERE</a>
<div id="first" class="notification">first</div>
<div id="second" class="notification">second</div>
<div id="third" class="notification">third</div>
<div id="fouth" class="notification">fourth</div>
<div id="fifth" class="notification">fifth</div>
```